# Question on computing $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \tan^{-1} \left(\frac{3}{n^2 + n - 1}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, trigonometry, infinity, trigonometric-series

Find $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \tan^{-1} \left(\frac{3}{n^2 + n - 1}\right)$$

I know this can be simplified to a telescoping series of the form

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\tan^{-1}(n+2) - \tan^{-1}(n-1)$$

The correct answer, on evaluating the limit for this would be,

$\tan^{-1} (n+2) + \tan^{-1} (n+1) +\tan^{-1} (n)- \tan^{-1} 0 - \tan^{-1} (1) - \tan^{-1} (2) =\frac{ 3\pi}4 - \cot^{-1} 2$

But when summing to infinity why do we have remanent $\tan^{-1} (n+2) + \tan^{-1} (n+1) +\tan^{-1} (n)$ since for every $ \tan^{-1} n$ we would have a $-\tan^{-1} n$. Something similar to the argument how set of natural numbers and integers is equal $(n(N) = n(I))$.

In problems I've done before the telescoping sum usually tends to 0 so I might be thinking of it in the wrong way.

Comment: How do you get $\tan^{-1}(-2)$ term?

Comment: @BobDobbs it was a typo, corrected it

Comment: WolframAlpha says the answer is $\pi/2$ so that means we must take the typo $\tan^{-1}(-1)$ as $3\pi/4$? @failedC

Comment: $\arctan\left(\frac{3}{n^{2}+n-1}\right) \neq \arctan\left(n+2\right)-\arctan\left(n-1\right)$ when $n = 0$, but for all the other positive integers $n$, it holds.

Comment: @BobDobbs due to a particularly stupid mistake, I've written n=0 instead of n=1, but I've understood MathFail's answer. Thanks for your interest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you did is the partial sum

$$\begin{align}S_n&=\sum_{k=1}^n \tan^{-1} \left(\frac{3}{k^2 + k - 1} \right)\\
\\
S_n&=\tan^{-1} (n+2) + \tan^{-1} (n+1) +\tan^{-1} (n)- \tan^{-1} 0 - \tan^{-1} (1) - \tan^{-1} (2)\end{align}$$

the series equals the limit of the partial sum, namely

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \tan^{-1} \left(\frac{3}{k^2 + k - 1} \right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n=\frac{5\pi}4 - \tan^{-1} (2)$$

Comment: OP says "when summing to infinity why do we have remanent", so I guess it is confused on the partial sum and series notations.

Comment: why is the series equal to the limit of the partial sum. This is obviously not the answer but when we write down the telescoping summation, all the terms apart from $-\tan^{-1} 1 - \tan^{-1} 2$ appear to get cancelled

Comment: Series is defined by the limit of partial sum. So the formal way is to first evaluate the partial sum to some finite terms. In your OP, the partial sum is to evaluate it from $k=0$ to $k=n$, so totally $n+1$ terms, then you do the telescope and cancel those middle terms, and left with 6 terms. Finally take the limit by letting $n\to\infty$

Comment: OP changed the question.

Answer (score 2):

By using the identity
$$\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{n^2+n-1}\right)=\tan^{-1}(n+2)-\tan^{-1}(n-1)$$
for $n>0$, the $n$-th partial sum of the series
$$S= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{n^2+n-1}\right)$$
is
$$S_n=\tan^{-1}(n+2)+\tan^{-1}(n+1)+\tan^{-1}(n)
-\tan^{-1}(2)-\tan^{-1}(1)
-\tan^{-1}(0).$$
Letting $n\rightarrow\infty$ we have $$S=\frac{3\pi}{2}-\tan^{-1}2-\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{5\pi}{4}-\tan^{-1}2.$$

Answer (score 0):

Using $$
 \tan \left(\tan ^{-1} a-\tan ^{-1} b\right)=\frac{a-b}{1+a b}\Rightarrow \tan ^{-1} a-\tan ^{-1} b=\tan ^{-1} \left(\frac{a-b}{1+a b}\right),
$$
we have
$$
a-b=3 \text { and } 1+a b=n^2+n-1 \Rightarrow a=n+2 \textrm{ and } b=n-1.
$$
Hence $$
\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{n^2+n-1}\right)=\tan ^{-1}(n+2)-\tan ^{-1}(n-1)
$$
$$\begin{aligned}
S&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{n^2+n-1}\right)\\&=\lim _{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=0}^N\left[\tan ^{-1}(n+2)-\tan^{-1} (n-1)\right] \\&= \lim _{N \rightarrow \infty}\left[\sum_{n=2}^{N+2} \tan ^{-1} n -\sum_{n=-1}^{N-1} \tan ^{-1} n\right]\\&= \lim _{N \rightarrow \alpha}\left[\tan ^{-1}(N+2)+\tan ^{-1}(N+1)+\tan ^{-1} N\right] -\tan ^{-1}(-1)-\tan ^{-1}(0)-\tan ^{-1} 1\\&= \lim _{N \rightarrow \infty}\left[\tan ^{-1}(N+2)+\tan ^{-1}(N+1)+\tan ^{-1} N\right]\end{aligned}
$$
Using the identity twice
$$\tan ^{-1} a+\tan ^{-1} b=\tan ^{-1} \left(\frac{a+b}{1-a b}\right),$$
we have

$$S= \tan ^{-1} \frac{2 N+3}{1-(N+2)(N+1)}+\tan ^{-1} N =\lim _{N \rightarrow \infty} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{N-\frac{2 N+3}{N^2+3 N+1}}{1+\frac{2 N^2+3 N}{N^2+3 N+1}}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: OP changed the question.